# Is Open XML SDK 2.5 able to recalculate Excel formulas?

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I am struggling with the Open XML SDK and I've already read a lot of posts on this topic but cannot figure it out. My goal is to have a locally created Excel file which contains a formula and edit the input online and retrieve the calculated value online.

I don't know if this is possible since Open XML may only change the data and I wonder if it is also able to perform Excels calculations.

For example, my local file contains three cells:

```
A1: 1
A2: 2
A3: =(A1+A2)
```

Using Open XML I adjust A2 to the value of 3, however the result of A3 remains 3 instead of 4.

I have already read about Excel having to recalculate, but my goal is to have an Excel file as some sort of calculation engine instead of transfering all calculations to C#.

All tips and advice are welcome.

Kind regards, Patrick

Comment: What does the ML stand for in XML?

Comment: Please post your code. Formula calculation is performed by the *client*. Once you set the *correct* formula with Open XML SDK, whenever the user changes the inputs the formula will run. If it doesn't, it's because you didn't set the formula at all, or used the wrong code.

Comment: PS, why would you need C# to execute a formula? What did you actually try? Did you create an Open XML CellFormula object, set the Cell.Formula property or simply set the text of a cell to look like a formula?

Answer (score 1):

First of all thanks for all responses.
Second I guess the response answered my question and the open XML SDK is only able to adjust the file and won't do anything regarding recaculating existing formulas in the file. This will only occur when opened in Excel. I will take a look at EPPlus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
Cell cell; //supposing this is your cell referencing A3
CellFormula cellformula = new CellFormula();
cellformula.Text = "SUM(A1, A2)";
CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();
cellValue.Text = "0";
cell.Append(cellformula);
cell.Append(cellValue);
```

A similar example can be found at this link: [Formula cells in excel using openXML](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b28a9f9c-9ad7-4eea-adab-b062883c11e2/formula-cells-in-excel-using-openxml?forum=oxmlsdk)

Comment: `Cell` already has a [Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx). `cell.Text = "SUM(A1, A2)";` is enough. I suspect the forum link treats the objects as XML elements instead of actually using the SDK's API

Answer (score 0):

I feel there could be some ambiguity captured in the question. `OpenXML` is way of storing documents, therefore it is not possible to do calculations with `OpenXML SDK`. It is spread sheet engine (`Excel` application) which performs the calculations.

When inputs are updated, spreadsheet saved, calculated values should get updated.

Comment: I think the OP is asking why the formula doesn't run when end users change the inputs. These settings would only affect recalculation when loading. It's possible that the OP didn't set the `Formula` property at all

Comment: PS, libraries like EPPlus include [their own calculation engine](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=About+Formula+calculation)  to recalculate results when creating a file. By necessity, only a subset of functions is supported.

Comment: Thanks for comments @PanagiotisKanavos makes sense. Adjusted the answer.